# Send Test Alert not working in Cloudera manager

Tags: cloudera, hadoop2, cloudera-manager

I have been trying to set up alert and monitoring in Cloudera manager and tried sending a 'test alert' to my email id. But I didn't receive any mail.

I am new and do not possess much knowledge in monitoring.

Can anyone help , what might be the issue here or where can I look for more information.